# jQuery Binding & JavaScript event.stopPropagation()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a TD that contains two divs. The first div contains text and is visible. The second div contains a textarea and is hidden by default. Using the code below, I've bound to the click event of the TD and swapped the visibility of the div's on click:

```
$(".tdEstimatorNote").click(function (e)
{
    $(this).find("div:first").toggle("400");
    $(this).find("div:first").next().toggle("400");
    $(this).find(".estimatorNotesTA").focus();
});
```

Although this works, it created an issue with the textarea. When I attempted to put the focus on the textarea after it became visible, the div's would swap visibility again (because I'm bound to the click event of the TD). So, my solution, stop the event propagation:

```
$(".estimatorNotesTA").click(function (event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This works - sort of. I'm able to freely edit and click inside the textarea now, but I'm not able to range select any text (I'm assuming because of the jQuery above). It's possible that my assumption is incorrect, because I'm unable to range select text via the keyboard as well (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>end</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>home</kbd>). Any thoughts / suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure where the problem comes from, but you can just test whether the textarea was clicked:

```
$(".tdEstimatorNote").click(function (e){
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('estimatorNotesTA')) {
        //Toggle CSS class
        // use method chaining :)
        $(this)
           .find("div:first").toggle("400");
              .next().toggle("400").end()
           .end()
           .find(".estimatorNotesTA").focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the target checking. As for the method chaining, is there any advantage to it? Personally, it seems less readable to me than my code (personal preference obviously)? Still have the range select issue...

Comment: @JamesHill: Did you remove the click event handler from the textarea? You have to. If this does not solve it, the problem seems to be somewhere else. Regarding chaining: You should at least do `$(this).find("div:first").toggle("400").next().toggle("400")` instead of searching twice for the same element. You already have a reference to `div:first`, you don't need to search again.

Comment: Yes, I removed the click event handler from the textarea. Great point about the secondary search.

Comment: @JamesHill: Mmh. And you are sure that selecting text works if you don't attach the event handler at all? Could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo?

Comment: @FilixKling, Your hunch was correct - it wasn't the event handler. It was this silly line of code that I overlooked (in my copy+paste from jquery ui's sortable demo) `$("ul, li").disableSelection();`. All is well, and I've learned method chaining in jQuery. I'll add this to the list of my life's embarassing moments...

Comment: @JamesHill: :D No worries, these things happen all the time ;) Glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the "return home early" pattern, which saves you one indentation level and perhaps help with the readability too.

```
$(".tdEstimatorNote").click(function (e){
    if( $(e.target).hasClass('estimatorNotesTA') ) return;

    //Toggle CSS class
    // use method chaining :)
    $(this)
       .find("div:first").toggle("400");
       .next().toggle("400").end()
       .end()
       .find(".estimatorNotesTA").focus();
});
```